# Send(deposit) ether from my wallet(msg.sender) to contract(this)

Tags: solidity

I want to make a function for depositing ether in the contract. I made a simple test contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract depo {
    function depo() public {

    }

    function () payable public {

    }

    function deposit() payable public {
        this.transfer(1 ether);
    }
}
```

After I deploy the contract and I run the `deposit` function, an error occurs.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Payments to a contract do not work the way you intend.

The contract cannot define how much ether the user will send. Instead, the user creates a transaction where they define the amount of ether they send (`msg.value`).

If you specifically want to create a function where the user can only deposit 1 ether, then it would look like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract depo {
    function depo() public {

    }

    function () payable public {

    }

    function deposit() payable public {
        require(msg.value == 1 ether);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The function to send ether from my account to the contract is what I intended. 1 ether is just an example. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You cannot create a function which pulls ether out of someone else's account.